# Software recommendation to view git-conflict side by side?

Tags: linux, git, version-control, diff

I am doing some git merging and there is a conflict.

Usually the conflicts are small (less than 10 lines) but this has lots of conflicts that are more than 10 lines each.

**What software would you recommend to view the conflict side by side?**

Can I use `vimdiff`?

Currently I just open the file with conflicts in vim and manually edit.

Comment: Personally, I like Kdiff3, but as you don't give many requirements, there are many possible answers

Answer (score 1):

The [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) plugin has a nice "Gdiff" command that allows you to show the conflicts side-by-side. I use it quite regularly and most of the time it's OK for me. There's a [screencast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-resolving-merge-conflicts-with-vimdiff/) about its use as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a lot of diff viewers:

1. [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/)
2. [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/)
3. [Kompare](https://www.kde.org/applications/development/kompare/).
4. [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/) (yeah, I went there).
5. [Vim](https://www.vim.org/) (and there too!).
6. [Diffuse](http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/)

That's all I can remember right now.